# Webcam creates repeated error messages "Cannot set freg 16000"

Tags: 11.10, webcam

When I connect my Logitech Quickcam 3000 the terminal starts with the following error message:

```
cannot set freq 16000 to ep 0x86
```

It continues until I disconnect the webcam. What can I do to solve this?

NOTE - The webcam works correctly in every sense. This is the only weird thing that happens when I connect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug, unfortunately not fully resolved.

For more details and possible workarounds see

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/567565

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/459445